# get latest file name from directory ROBOT test case

Tags: robotframework

```
@{files}=   List Files In Directory     Z:\\    *base*.zip


    ${lastModifiedFile} =   Get From List   ${files}    0
    log to console      Z://${lastModifiedFile}

    @{time1} =  OperatingSystem.Get Modified Time       Z://${lastModifiedFile}


      :FOR    ${file}    IN    @{files}
\       @{time1} =  OperatingSystem.Get Modified Time       Z://${lastModifiedFile}
\       @{time} =   Get Modified Time   ${file}
\       Run Keyword If  ${time1} < ${time}
\       ...     ${lastModifiedFile} ${file}
\       ... ELSE    log to console  ${file}
```

I have written this code to get latest file from the directory. Its not working!!

Comment: what do you mean it isn't working?  Are you getting errors?  What is actually happening?

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Where is the question? The problem you are having is you are comparing strings, not times. Simple fix is to have Get Modified Time return the time in epoch time (integer). The largest number will be the most recently modified one.

Answer (score 2):

```
@{files}=   List Files In Directory     Z:\\    *base*.zip

${lastModifiedFile} =   Get From List   ${files}    0
${time1} =  OperatingSystem.Get Modified Time       Z://${lastModifiedFile}    epoch

:FOR    ${file}    IN    @{files}
\    ${time}    Get Modified Time   ${file}    epoch
\    ${lastModifiedFile}    Set Variable If    ${time1} < ${time}    ${file}    ${lastModifiedfile}
\    ${time1}    Set Variable If    ${time1} < ${time}    ${time}    ${time1}
```

Comment: add some description to it.

Comment: get all the files in Z:\\ with pattern *base*.zip. get the first file name and its modified date as the initial 'latest'. then just go through the list getting the modified time and if it's later than the current 'latest' then it will be the 'latest'.